# call webmethod from android using ksoap2

Tags: android, eclipse, ksoap2

I am trying to call webmethod from android using ksoap2. I set parameters of webmethod using soapobject method addProperty but can not set parameter in webmethod.
I create one AsyncTask class and its doInBackgroud() method override and call webmethod from it.

```
 cannot set webmethod parameters
```

Following is the code:

```
package com.example.locumapllication;

import android.os.AsyncTask;

public class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Object> {

private String METHOD_NAME="";
private String NAMESPACE="http://ws.easyway3e.com/";
private String SOAP_ACTION="";
private static final String URL="http://192.168.2.155:8080/WebService/DBConn?wsdl";

@Override
protected Object doInBackground(String... params) {

    System.out.println("Call-1"+params[0]+params[1]+params[2]+params[3]);
    METHOD_NAME="openConnection";               
    SoapObject request=new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);



    request.addProperty("arg0",params[0]);
    request.addProperty("arg1",params[1]);
    request.addProperty("arg2",params[2]);
    request.addProperty("arg3",params[3]);
    System.out.println("Property Set ="+request.getPropertyCount());

    SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);

    envelope.dotNet=true;
    envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);


    System.out.println(envelope.bodyOut.toString());

    HttpTransportSE androidHttpTranportSE=new HttpTransportSE(URL);


        try {
            SOAP_ACTION= METHOD_NAME + NAMESPACE;

            androidHttpTranportSE.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);

            SoapPrimitive  resultsRequestSOAP = (SoapPrimitive) envelope.getResponse();

                System.out.println(" Connection is =>"+resultsRequestSOAP.toString());

        } catch (IOException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Object result = null;
        try {
            result = envelope.getResponse();
        } catch (SoapFault e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    return result;
}
```

}

I can do soapobject's setproperty method to set property of webmethod but it can not set parameters of webmethod.

I have created webservices using jaxws, so I wish to know if there is any problem to integrate with ksoap2 and jaxws. Also guide me to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

look how proprty is set over here i hope this might help

```
    SoapObject Request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
  //parameters added here..  
  PropertyInfo pi = new PropertyInfo();
    pi.setName("EmailAddress");
    pi.setValue("dilip.mariya@gmail.com");
    pi.setType(String.class);
    Request.addProperty(pi);

 SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
    envelope.dotNet = true;
    envelope.setOutputSoapObject(Request);

    AndroidHttpTransport androidHttpTransport = new AndroidHttpTransport(URL);
    Log.e("above try","");
    try
    {
        androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
        SoapObject response = (SoapObject)envelope.bodyIn;

        String result =  (response.getProperty(0).toString());
       // String gfdgf =  (response.getProperty(1).toString());
        Log.e("", result);
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: i can do it but parameters are not set into webmethod

Answer (score 0):

Try to change your URL (if you are using the Virtual Device):

URL="http://10.0.2.2:8080/WebService/DBConn?wsdl"